# How to remove HTML tags in BeautifulSoup when I have contents

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

The html for what I'm attempting to grab:

`<div id="unitType">
     <h2>BB100 <br>v1.4.3</h2>
 </div>`

I have the contents of an `h2` tag below:

```
initialPage = beautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url).read(), 'html.parser')
deviceInfo = initialPage.find('div', {'id': 'unitType'}).h2.contents
print('Device Info: ', deviceInfo)
for i in deviceInfo:
    print i
```

Which outputs:

```
('Device Info: ', [u'BB100 ', <br>v1.4.3</br>])
BB100
<br>v1.4.3</br>
```

How do I remove the `<h2>`,`</h2>`,`<br>` and `</br>` html tags, using BeautifulSoup rather than regex? I've tried `i.decompose()` and `i.strip()` but neither has worked. It would throw `'NoneType' object is not callable`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `<br>` can't have anything in them. In HTML5, `</br>` is invalid.

Comment: Good point. Might just have to resort to string replacement. Not sure who wrote this code but they must be long gone.

Comment: @Richard, why are you iterating over the contents when you only want the br?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I still want both values. I'm just looking for a Beautiful Soup method to get rid of <br> and </br> while keeping "v.1.4.3". I don't need to iterate over the contents to modify them? This is my first stab at Beautiful Soup.

Comment: @Richard, no, you can use .find, .select, .find_all etc.. you don't need to go over all the contents, you can do a  replace-with as per my answer to replace and node with whatever you like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use find and *extract* the *br* tag:

```
In [15]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    ...: 
    ...: h = """<div id='unitType'><h2>BB10<br>v1.4.3</h2></d
    ...: iv>"""
    ...: 
    ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "html.parser")
    ...: 
    ...: h2 = soup.find(id="unitType").h2
    ...: h2.find("br").extract()
    ...: print(h2)
    ...: 
<h2>BB10</h2>
```

Or to replace the tag with just the text using [replace-with](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with):

```
In [16]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    ...: 
    ...: h = """<div id='unitType'><h2<br>v1.4.3 BB10</h2></d
    ...: iv>"""
    ...: 
    ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "html.parser")
    ...: 
    ...: h2 = soup.find(id="unitType").h2
    ...: 
    ...: br = h2.find("br")
    ...: br.replace_with(br.text)
    ...: print(h2)
    ...: 
<h2>v1.4.3 BB10</h2>
```

To remove the *h2* and keep the text:

```
In [37]: h = """<div id='unitType'><h2><br>v1.4.3</h2></d
    ...: 
    ...: iv>"""
    ...: 
    ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "html.parser")
    ...: 
    ...: unit = soup.find(id="unitType")
    ...: 
    ...: h2 = unit.find("h2")
    ...: h2.replace_with(h2.text)
    ...: print(unit)
    ...: 
<div id="unitType">v1.4.3 BB10</div>
```

If you just want `"v1.4.3"` and  `"BB10"`, there are many ways to hey them:

```
In [60]: h = """<div id="unitType">
    ...:      <h2>BB100 <br>v1.4.3</h2>
    ...:  </div>"""
    ...: 
    ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(h, "html.parser")
    ...: 
    ...: h2 = soup.find(id="unitType").h2
        # just find all strings
    ...: a,b = h2.find_all(text=True)
    ...: print(a, b)
         # get the br
    ...: br = h2.find("br")
        # get br text and just the h2 text ignoring any text from children
    ...: a, b = h2.find(text=True, recursive=False),  br.text
    ...: print(a, b)
    ...: 
BB100  v1.4.3
BB100  v1.4.3
```

Why you  end up with text ins

Comment: I'm looking to remove <br> and </br> while keeping "v1.4.3". In your first example, printing `h2` gives back `('Device Info: ', <h2>BB100 </h2>)`

Comment: Then you just need to use the second example.

Comment: What would your approach be in then removing the h2 tags? I need "BB100" and "v1.4.3" as separate string values.

Comment: So you just want the text?

Comment: Yes sir. So I can compare the string text values against other strings. Verifying the model and firmware versions against a csv list.

Comment: I added the html of the div to the question above.

Comment: Looking at it now, I'm not sure why soup was printing `</br>` when the HTML itself doesn't have `</br>`.

Comment: @Richard, there is no closing tag so the parser adds it after the text, if you print the soup object you will see it's there

Comment: I see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element is a `<br>` tag with `if i.name == 'br'`, and then just change the list to have the contents instead.

```
for i in deviceInfo:
    if i.name == 'br':
        i = i.contents
```

If you need to iterate over it many times, modify the list.

```
for n, i in enumerate(deviceInfo):
    if i.name == 'br':
        i = i.contents
        deviceInfo[n] = i
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Building from what you had, I added `print i[0]` which would return "v1.4.3".